# Filtered DistinctCount Measure and MDX Not Delivering Same Results as SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, sql-server-2016

I have the following two queries, one SQL, one MDX:

SQL:

```
SELECT t.term_report_year, COUNT(*)
FROM(
     SELECT DISTINCT de.term_report_year, fe.student_id
     FROM warehouse.FactEnrolments fe
     INNER JOIN warehouse.DimDate dd
     ON fe.term_record_creation_fk = dd.DateKey
     INNER JOIN warehouse.DimTermEnrolments de
     ON fe.term_enrolments_fk = de.term_enrolments_pk
     WHERE dd.ISOWeekNumberOfYear <= 8 OR dd.ISOYearCode < de.term_report_year
) t
GROUP BY t.term_report_year
ORDER BY term_report_year
```

MDX:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Measures.[Enrolments] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      Filter
      (
            [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].Children *
            [Term Record Creation].[ISO Year Code].children *
            [Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Number Of Year].children
       ,
        Cint([Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Number Of Year].CurrentMember.Member_Key) <= 8
        OR
        Cint([Term Record Creation].[ISO Year Code].CurrentMember.Member_key) < Cint([Term Enrolments].[Term Year].CurrentMember.Member_key)
      ) ON ROWS
FROM [Enrolments];
```

I am trying to express the idea in both, "count the number of students in a year who enrolled for that year before or during the 8th week of that year" where `year = term_year`.

In my SSAS cube the `Enrolments` measure is a `DistinctCount` on `student_id`. In the `SQL` query, `term_report_year` is equivalent to `Term Year` in the `MDX`.

Could someone please explain why the two queries are not delivering the same numbers e.g. the `SQL` for 2016 gives 2803 and the `MDX` 2948?

I think it has something to do with the MDX double counting across the weeks, but I can't work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I am hopeful it will filter the year total to just weeks <= 8

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Measures.[Enrolments] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY  [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].Children ON ROWS
FROM (
 SELECT
      Filter
      (
            [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].Children *
            [Term Record Creation].[ISO Year Code].children *
            [Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Number Of Year].children
       ,
        Cint([Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Number Of Year].CurrentMember.Member_Key) <= 8
        OR
        Cint([Term Record Creation].[ISO Year Code].CurrentMember.Member_key) < Cint([Term Enrolments].[Term Year].CurrentMember.Member_key)
      ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Enrolments]
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works. Are you able to explain a little why it works and the other one doesn't, please? I don't really understand what is happening in the query.

Comment: @fluffybonkers sure. The FROM clause with the subquery returns only the weeks <= 8. That way when you retrieve the yearly total it is not the whole year total but the subset which is from week <= 8.